# Boolean comparisons in one line vs multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I wasn't sure what to name the title. But I'm new to programming in general and I'm using python. My question is, how come just writing return instead of a bunch if and else statements work exactly the same.

```
#Multiple lines
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
  if talking:
    if hour <7 or hour >20:
      return True
  return False
#One line
def parrot_trouble(talking, hour):
  return (talking and (hour < 7 or hour > 20))
```

Both these codes yield the exact same results.. but why? sorry I'm super new

Comment: It's been updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both these codes yield the exact same results

That's incorrect. It is only true where the inputs are of specific types. Consider this trivial counter-example:

```
def parrot_trouble1(talking, hour):
    if talking:
        if hour < 7 or hour > 20:
            return True
    return False

def parrot_trouble2(talking, hour):
    return (talking and (hour < 7 or hour > 20))

parrot_trouble1([], 0)  # False
parrot_trouble2([], 0)  # []
```

#### [But note `and` / `or` are designed this way:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

> Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return
>   to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument.

`parrot_trouble2` exhibits short-circuiting. Let's assume that `talking` is a Boolean input.  If `talking` is `False`, the expression short-circuits and returns `False`. If `talking` is `True`, `parrot_trouble2` will return `True` or `False` depending on the value of `hour`.

`parrot_trouble1` doesn't short-circuit, but the result is the same. If `talking` is Boolean and `False`, the function returns `False`. If `talking` is `True`, then the second criterion `hour < 7 or hour > 20` is tested. If the condition is not specified then, since nothing is returned, Python move's outside and after the `if` statement to `return False`.

Comment: Thank you this really helped me understand what was going on.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of having

```
if condition == True:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

in a function, you could just have it return the condition

```
return condition
```

since you're checking for the same value you would return